# Creating Stored Procedures and declaring foreign keys

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am creating a stored procedure for an airline reservation system and the procedure has to allow me to add a new flight with a valid plane type, not to allow duplicates, the destination city and departure city cannot be the same and the total passengers booked is defaulted to 0.

I have created two tables plane and flight and I listed plane id as a foreign key in the flight table however I'm not sure how to validate the plane type from the plane table on the flight table. should I make plane type a foreign key instead?
below is my code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Addnewflight @f_id int, @dep_city varchar(50), @dest_city varchar(50), @no numeric(12,2), @dt datetime, @total_passenger numeric(12,2)
AS
DECLARE @count INT;
SET @count= (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM dbo.flight where flight_id=@f_id)
IF @count=0 AND @dep_city<>@dest_city 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.[flight]([flight_id],[departure city],[destination city],[number],[date],[total number of passengers]) VALUES(@f_id,@dep_city,@dest_city,@no,@dt,@total_passenger)
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    PRINT 'Duplicates are not allowed.  Destination and departure city cannot be the same.';
END
```

Comment: Where does plane type come from? Is it a parameter into your stored procedure? Doesn't look like it. Is a `plane_type_id` looked up inside the procedure somehow, based on criteria that you haven't mentioned?

Comment: the plane type is a column within my dbo.plane. and I did not put it into the procedure now that I am looking over it. within my store procedure should I add as a check constraint?

Comment: Well, no, I don't think so. How do you know what plane you want to use? What is the `select` statement you will use to get the plane type from the plane table? Let's start with that.

Comment: I use SELECT Plane Type FROM dbo.plane WHERE plane type=747;

Answer (score 0):

In your stored procedure, declare a variable for plane type:

```
declare @plane_type varchar(max);
```

Then set the variable using your select statement (taken from the comments above):

```
set @plane_type = (SELECT [Plane Type] FROM dbo.plane WHERE [Plane Type]=747)
```

(I added the square brackets around the column name because it looks like it contains a space character.)

Then in your `insert` statement, add the Plane Type:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.[flight]([flight_id],[plane type],[departure city],[destination city],[number],[date],[total number of passengers]) VALUES(@f_id,@plane_type,@dep_city,@dest_city,@no,@dt,@total_passenger)
```